# Sum numbers after 100 billion doesn't work in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I use sequelize for my models and create model like this

```
@Table({tableName: 'UserData'})
export default class UserDataModel extends Model<UserDataInterface> {
  @Default(0)
  @Column(DataType.DECIMAL(30, 4))
  balance: number;

  @Default(0)
  @Column(DataType.DECIMAL(30, 4))
  record: number;
```

Add numbers like this

```
UserDataModel.update({
          balance: Sequelize.literal('balance + click'),
          record: Sequelize.literal('record + click')
        }, {
          individualHooks: true,
          where: {
            userId: user.id
          }
        });
```

Type of click is

```
@Default(0)
  @Column(DataType.DOUBLE)
  click: number;
```

Click in my case is = 0.0001 and if i try sum 90 000 000 000.0000 + 0.0001 it's work, but if number is more then 100 billion like 100 000 000 000 + 0.0001 it isn't work, why is this happening and what should I do?

package.json

```
"sequelize": "^5.22.4",
    "sequelize-auto-migrations": "^1.0.3",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^1.1.0",
```

Comment: The specified DECIMAL will only work while the data is in the database; other parts of the system may be using IEEE floats, which are subject to (different) rounding rules. You'll need to be meticulous about never using the IEEE floats to handle your DECIMAL(30, 4) numbers to avoid this rounding.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: I mean, while the database will work with 30 significant figure fixed-point decimal as you specified, for the columns where you specified it, the rest of the system will continue to default to the usual 15-17 significant figure floating-point DOUBLE format. Now that I read more carefully, this includes the `click` column, which you specified as `DOUBLE`. You need to make sure this is converted to `DECIMAL(30, 4)` _before_ the addition.

Comment: Oh thanks, you were right, i changed click to `DECIMAL(30, 4)` and it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to change column type to same if you won't sum big decimal, all columns that you sum